# SpringBoot : Expand Child Object in RestController Response

Tags: java, spring-boot

Good Morning Community,

I am new to SringBoot (and Java).

I can't succeed to do a simple task : Create a `controller` that return a Car and its Driver in `json`.

I have this response :

`{"color":"red","driver":"example"}`

I want :

`{"color":"red","driver":{"name": "example"}}`

Is it possible to do it without an `ObjectMapper`, I hope there is an annotation that do the trick.

Thank you for your time, have a nice day.

My Controller :

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class CarController {

    @GetMapping("/car/{driverName}")
    public Car cars(
            @PathVariable(value = "driverName") String driverName
    ) {
        driverName = "example";
        Driver driver = new Driver();
        driver.setName(driverName);
        Car car = new Car();
        car.setDriver(driver);
       return car;
    }
}
```

My Car Class :

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Component
public class Car {

    public Driver driver;
    public String color ="red";

    public Car() {
    }

    public String getDriver() {
        return this.driver;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setDriver(Driver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

My Driver Class :

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Component
public class Driver {

    public String name;

    public Driver() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a list of Driver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem in your `Car` class, the `getDriver` method returns a `String` but it should return the `Driver` object, try with:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Component
public class Car {

    public Driver driver;
    public String color ="red";

    public Car() {
    }

    public Driver getDriver() {
        return this.driver;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setDriver(Driver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Component
public class Car {

    public Driver driver;
    public String color ="red";

    public Car() {
    }

    public Driver getDriver() {
        return this.driver;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setDriver(Driver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).